# Cannot make button look smooth in css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a requirement on designing a button and when I use the tag button from react it looks pretty ugly and I tried to design it with no avail.

I will post a picture of the zeplin requirement and the picture of my button along with css code.
[image: Button requirements]

My css code

```
.textField::placeholder{
  width: 600px;
  height: 47px;
}

.signIn{
  width: 100px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-color: #f1316b;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 45px;
}
```

So basically the problem is along the broder that thick line of white and grayness that makes it so ugly
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try to add box-shadow: 0px 0px 0p; to signIn class in css.

Answer (score 3):

Buttons by default have border, if you dont have a css reset file just add `border: 0` and it should remove the border

Comment: That totally fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

To add a smoothness to your button simply means that you want to hide the borders of the button. There is only one line of CSS that you can add to your class.

Just add this: **border:none** property to your stylesheet. Look at the code output that I have prepared for you.

**Note:** Since I have no structure of your button, I have simply written it as HTML markup. However, the CSS syntax will be the same if the class name to your button is same.

```css
.signIn{
  width: 100px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-color: #f1316b;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="signIn" value="Sign In"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

give border none or anything what you want like  border: '1px #d6d4d4 solid',